# Why I got null value when try send post request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I try to send post request to change password two parameters are ok, but the token value is null and i can't change password. When user want to change password he got uri with token, when he clicked on this link user is redirecting to change password page and after fill area 'password' and 'matchPassword' and try to send form the token value is null

```
    @GetMapping("/resetPassword")
    public String resetPassword(Model model,@RequestParam("passwordToken") String token){
        String result = passwordService.validatePasswordResetToken(token);
        if (result != null){
            throw new UserNotFoundException("Token not exist");
        }
        model.addAttribute("token",token);
        model.addAttribute("user",passwordService.getUserByPasswordResetToken(token));
        return "updatePassword";
    }

    @PostMapping("/resetPassword")
    public String updatePassword(String password,String matchPassword, String token){
    User user = passwordService.getUserByPasswordResetToken(token);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setMatchPassword(matchPassword);
    userService.save(user);
    return "success";
}
```

and how look html page updatePassword.html

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/resetPassword}">
    <input type="password" th:field="${user.password}">
    <input type="password" th:field="${user.matchPassword}">
    <button type="submit">Update Password</button>
</form>
```

Token generator endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/forget-password")
    public String forgetPassword(String email){
        User user= userService.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null){
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User with this email doesn't exist");
        }
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        userService.createPasswordResetTokenForUser(user,token);

        userService.sendMessageWithResetPassword(user,token);
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the PasswordService so we can see what is going on in there. If the token is coming back as null, then the problem is most likely originating from there.

Comment: I added PasswordService class also :)

Comment: Where does the token come from and what does it represent? It looks like it's null right now because it is not being passed to your POST method.

Comment: token is needed to change password each token has user, when user send request to endpoint /forget-password token is generate, save in db and additional send email messege with link to change password for example: http://localhost:8080/resetPassword?passwordToken=a34037b2-aa22-434b-9865-7fee45ffdb64
so when user go to this endpoint he has additional fields to save new password
EDIT: added endpoint where token is generate

Comment: Have you any idea?